# Python image file without extension

Tags: python, image, file

I am trying to read image files from [this website.](http://courses.media.mit.edu/2004fall/mas622j/04.projects/faces/)

Let's say the file name is "1223" in the working directory

```
f = open("1223")
image = f.read()
```

Then I get a long string something like '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00.....'

I am not sure how to read this as an image file.

Comment: Image files are binary, so something like this this `open('1223', 'rb')`. But that's not terribly useful for most of us. Usually one picks an imaging processing library that does stuff you want.

Comment: I tried `open('1223', 'rb')` but it results in the same string.

Comment: Might I ask what you are expecting? The string you refer to is the bytecode of the image...

Comment: I am trying to convert this into 128 by 128 pixels.

Comment: Okay, good info! How do you want that represented? `numpy` or `pandas` perhaps? How big is each pixel?

Comment: Numpy will be great. I think this is grayscale image. I don't know much about the image yet because I haven't processed it.

Comment: [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) would be another good place to start.